# Am I setting I2C CCR and TRISE wrong? STM32 [bare-metal]

Tags: c, stm32, accelerometer, i2c, bare-metal

<sup>*Following @wovano's suggestion, I'll be boiling down the question. For the old versions of the question, see the editing history.*</sup>

#### Overview

I'm trying to include I2C on my project ([STM32F407ZGT6](https://github.com/mcauser/BLACK_F407ZG), [MMA8452Q](https://www.nxp.com/docs/en/data-sheet/MMA8452Q.pdf) accelerometer) and I'm setting everything bare-metal. I'm using [gschorcht library](https://github.com/gschorcht/mma845x-esp-idf) for the accelerometer functions. I currently do not have access to an osciloscope nor to an FT232H.

#### Problem

I am unsure if my I2C is working properly: when I try to read my Device ID, I get 0x22 instead of [0x2A](https://www.nxp.com/docs/en/data-sheet/MMA8452Q.pdf)*. I'm also not being able to read data in a loop. If I use [`if (mma845x_new_data (sensor) && mma845x_get_float_data (sensor, &data))`](https://github.com/gschorcht/mma845x-esp-idf/blob/d043b224d53fd4b524743b73d72b0744fa6a242d/main/mma845x_example.c#L102), I never get a positive condition, and adjusting as below forces me into the *Default_Handler: Infinite_Loop* for debugging:

```c
void read_data(void)
{
    mma845x_float_data_t  data;
    if (mma845x_new_data (sensor))
    {
        if(mma845x_get_float_data (sensor, &data))
        {
        // max. full scale is +-16 g and best resolution is 1 mg, i.e. 5 digits
        printf("[MMA845X (xyz)[g]] ax=%+7.3f ay=%+7.3f az=%+7.3f\n", data.ax, data.ay, data.az);
        return;
        }
    }
    printf("[not new MMA845X (xyz)[g]] ax=%+7.3f ay=%+7.3f az=%+7.3f\n", data.ax, data.ay, data.az);
}
```

The Debug tab shows this trace/breakpoint trap thread:
[image: Debug trace/breakpoint trap]

I'm wondering if I did something wrong with my CCR or TRISE setting (I included below the calculations I'm using). I have my `SYSCLK` at 168MHz and `APB1` at 42MHz (`APB1PRESC` = 4), and I'm currently testing the *Standard Mode*.

#### Things I have right

1. the [board](https://cdn2.botland.store/96705-medium_default/3-axis-mma8452-i2c-digital-accelerometer-hw-616.jpg) has all pull-up resistors properly placed
2. MODER and AFR are properly set
3. the SA0 is set to high- or low-logical level to match the [device address](https://github.com/gschorcht/mma845x-esp-idf/blob/d043b224d53fd4b524743b73d72b0744fa6a242d/components/mma845x/mma845x.h#L50)
4. STOP is being sent after reading data from DR

#### Code

```c
void init_gpio(void)
{
    RCC->AHB1ENR |= RCC_AHB1ENR_GPIOBEN;    //Port B

    GPIOB->MODER  |= (2U << 12U);   //MMA845_SCL || PB6
    GPIOB->AFR[0] |= (4U << 24U);   //AF4
    GPIOB->OTYPER |= (1U << 6U);    //Output Type to Open Drain
    GPIOB->PUPDR  |= (1U << 12U);   //Set to Pull-Up

    GPIOB->MODER  |= (2U << 14U);   //MMA845_SDA || PB7
    GPIOB->AFR[0] |= (4U << 28U);   //AF4
    GPIOB->OTYPER |= (1U << 7U);    //Output Type to Open Drain
    GPIOB->PUPDR  |= (1U << 14U);   //Set to Pull-Up
}

/*i2c_init*/
void i2c_init(I2C_TypeDef *I2Cx)
{
    /*Enable clock access to I2Cs*/
    RCC->APB1ENR |= RCC_APB1ENR_I2C1EN; //enable I2C1
//  RCC->APB1ENR |= RCC_APB1ENR_I2C2EN; //enable I2C2
//  RCC->APB1ENR |= RCC_APB1ENR_I2C3EN; //enable I2C3
    RCC->APB1ENR;

    /*Reset I2C*/
    I2Cx->CR1 |= I2C_CR1_SWRST;    /*!BUSY ON */
    I2Cx->CR1 &= ~I2C_CR1_SWRST;   /*!BUSY OFF*/

    int CCR_VAL;
    int TRISE_VAL;
    int MAX_FRQ;

    /*Set I2C frequency same as APB*/
    MAX_FRQ = (SYSCLK/APB1PRESC)/1000000;   //= 42 @ max clock speed
    I2Cx->CR2 &= ~msk(6,0);        /*!BUSY ON*/
    I2Cx->CR2 |= MAX_FRQ;

    if(!MASTER_MODE){
        /* Standard Mode = 100kb/s*/
        /* CCR calculated by half-period of 100k
         * divided by the period of the PCLK
         * CCR = ((1/100'000)/2)/(1/42'000'000)
         * CCR = 5000ns/~24ns = 210
         */
        CCR_VAL = 210;
        /* TRISE calculated by PCLK (in MHz) + 1
         * TRISE = ((42'000'000/1'000'000) + 1)
         * TRISE = 42 + 1 = 43
         */
        TRISE_VAL = 43;
    }
    else
    {
        /*Fast Mode = 400kb/s*/
        if(DUTY_MODE)
        {
            /*16:9 ratio*/
            /* CCR calculated by half-period of 100k
             * divided by the sum of the duty ratios
             * divided by the period of the PCLK
             * t_high = 9 * CCR * TPCLK
             * t_low  = 16 * CCR * TPCLK
             * t_high + t_low = 25 * CCR * TPCLK
             * CCR = ((1/400'000)/2) / (25/42'000'000)
             * CCR = 1250ns/~595ns = 2.1 ~ 2
             */
            CCR_VAL = 2;
        }
        else
        {
            //2:1 ratio
            /* CCR calculated by half-period of 100k
             * divided by the sum of the duty ratios
             * divided by the period of the PCLK
             * t_high = CCR * TPCLK
             * t_low  = 2 * CCR * TPCLK
             * t_high + t_low = 3 * CCR * TPCLK
             * CCR = ((1/400'000)/2) / (3/42'000'000)
             * CCR = 1250ns/~71ns = 17.5 ~ 17
             */
            CCR_VAL = 17;
        }
        /* TRISE calculated by PCLK (in MHz) * 0.3ms + 1
         * TRISE = ((42'000'000/1'000'000)*(300/1000) + 1)
         * TRISE = 42 * 0.3 + 1 = 13.6 ~ 14
         */
        TRISE_VAL = 14;
    }

    /*Set Clock Control value*/
    I2Cx->CCR |= CCR_VAL;   //assuming APB1 = 42MHz, SM = True
    I2Cx->CCR |= (set(DUTY_MODE,I2C_CCR_DUTY_Pos) | set(MASTER_MODE,I2C_CCR_FS_Pos));

    I2Cx->TRISE |= TRISE_VAL;   //assuming APB1 = 42MHz, SM = True
    /*Enable I2C*/
    I2Cx->CR1 |= I2C_CR1_PE;
}

void set_addr(I2C_TypeDef *I2Cx, uint8_t sAddr, const uint8_t *mAddr, int read)
{
    volatile int temp;
    /*Check I2C is not busy*/
    while(I2Cx->SR2 & I2C_SR2_BUSY);

    /*(1) Generate a START, wait for start flag*/
    I2Cx->CR1 |= I2C_CR1_START;
    while (!(I2Cx->SR1 & I2C_SR1_SB));

    /*Transmit slave address + 'write'*/
    I2Cx->DR = sAddr << 1;

    /*Wait for the address flag*/
    while (!(I2Cx->SR1 & I2C_SR1_ADDR));
    temp = I2Cx->SR2; //Clear address flag

    /*Send memory address*/
    //Make sure TXE is emtpy
    while (!(I2Cx->SR1 & I2C_SR1_TXE));
    I2Cx->DR = mAddr;
    //Wait until transmitter is emtpy
    while (!(I2Cx->SR1 & I2C_SR1_TXE));

    if(read)
    {
        /*(2) Generate a START, wait for start flag*/
        I2Cx->CR1 |= I2C_CR1_START;
        while (!(I2Cx->SR1 & I2C_SR1_SB));

        /*Transmit slave address + 'read'*/
        I2Cx->DR = (sAddr << 1) | 1;

        /*Wait for the address flag*/
        while (!(I2Cx->SR1 & I2C_SR1_ADDR));
        temp = I2Cx->SR2; //Clear address flag
    }
}

int i2c_burst_read(I2C_TypeDef *I2Cx, uint8_t sAddr, const uint8_t *mAddr, uint8_t *string, uint32_t size)
{
    if(size == 0)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    uint8_t *pData = string;    //points at the first byte (char) of string
    set_addr(I2Cx, sAddr, mAddr, 1);

    /*Enable ACK*/
    I2Cx->CR1 |= I2C_CR1_ACK;

    while(size > 0U)
    {
        if(size-- == 1)
        {
            /*Disable ACK*/
            I2Cx->CR1 &= ~I2C_CR1_ACK;

            /*Wait until the receive flag is set*/
            while(!(I2Cx->SR1 & I2C_SR1_RXNE));

            //"Generate STOP" was here before

            /*Read data from the DR*/
            *pData++ = I2Cx->DR;
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            /*Wait until the receive flag is set*/
            while(!(I2Cx->SR1 & I2C_SR1_RXNE));

            /*Read data from the DR*/
            *pData++ = I2Cx->DR;
        }
    }
    /*Generate a STOP after receiving*/
    I2Cx->CR1 |= I2C_CR1_STOP;
    return 1;
}

int i2c_burst_write(I2C_TypeDef *I2Cx, uint8_t sAddr, const uint8_t *mAddr, uint8_t *string, uint32_t size)
{
    uint8_t *pData = string;    //points at the first byte (char) of string
    set_addr(I2Cx, sAddr, mAddr, 0);

    while(size > 0U)
    {
        /*Wait for transmitter to be empty*/
        while(!(I2Cx->SR1 & I2C_SR1_TXE));

        I2Cx->DR = *pData++;
        size--;
    }

    /*Wait for byte transfer finished flag*/
    while(!(I2Cx->SR1 & I2C_SR1_BTF));

    /*Generate a STOP after writing*/
    I2Cx->CR1 |= I2C_CR1_STOP;
    return 1;
}
```

*<sub>This might be due to it being a "different brand". Although it raises some suspicion that it isn't reading all the bits (0x2A in binary is `0b0010 1010` and 0x22 is `0b0010 0010`), testing it with another accelerometer gives me the value of 0x05. There's a chance bits are being lost but I'm not sure.</sub>

Comment: If this is a flag of the nature "read status register followed by read data register, in order to clear flag", then there's a classic well-known problem with debuggers reading the memory map and thereby causing this problem. If that's the cause then the program will work fine when free running/runnning without debugger, but break when you single step or use breakpoints etc.

Comment: Does the printf statement work at all? It could also be the case that the floating-point code is not included (linked) correctly, so the printf causes a Hardfault.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured my I2C communication was actually working! So the answer is 'Yes, my CCR and TRISE' settings were correct (at least for the 100kHz mode). To check this, I borrowed an Arduino and I pastade a simple `Wire` code to read and write from the line. With it, I discovered that:

1. I could read and write to the I2C bus (without register address)
2. I had problems when using the register address `mAddr`
3. The chip's ID is actually 0x2A

I was mistakenly sending to the function the address of the variable containing the memory address instead of its content (instead of `mAddr = 0x1D`, I was passing `&mAddr` as argument).

Also, @wovano guess about the HardFault was correct too. The printf was causing the crash, either because of the floating-point linkage or because it was reading an empty variable (since it wasn't getting any data).

I'm still having issues reading data from the MMA since my `STATUS->ZYXDR` flag never goes high (`mma845x_new_data(sensor)` always returns 0). My initialization is as follows, in case anyone has experience with Freescale semiconductors ([library link](https://github.com/gschorcht/mma845x-esp-idf)):

```c
#include "mma845x.h"

#define MMA845X_I2C_ADDRESS_1           0x1c  // SDO pin is low
#define MMA845X_I2C_ADDRESS_2           0x1d  // SDO pin is high

static mma845x_sensor_t* sensor;

void init_MMA_sensor(void)
{
    sensor = mma845x_init_sensor(I2C1, MMA845X_I2C_ADDRESS_2);
    mma845x_config_int_signals(sensor, mma845x_high_active, mma845x_push_pull);
    mma845x_config_hpf(sensor, 0, true);
    mma845x_set_scale(sensor, mma845x_scale_2_g);
    mma845x_set_mode(sensor, mma845x_high_res, mma845x_odr_50, true, false); //make it active!
}

void read_data(void)
{
     mma845x_float_data_t  data;
     if (mma845x_new_data(sensor))
     {
         if(mma845x_get_float_data(sensor, &data))
        {
            // max. full scale is +-16 g and best resolution is 1 mg, i.e. 5 digits
            printf("[MMA845X (xyz)[g]] ax=%+7.3f ay=%+7.3f az=%+7.3f\r\n",
                    data.ax, data.ay, data.az);
            return;
         }
     }
     printf("No new data available\r\n");
}

int main(void)
{
    /*Setup*/
    clock_init_168();
    init_systick_MS(SYSTICK_LOAD_VAL_MS);
    gpio_init();
    uart_init();
    i2c_init(I2C1);
    init_MMA_sensor();

    for(;;)
    {
        read_data();
        delayMS(500);
    }
}
```

But the intial question is resolved. Thanks for all your insight.